# Webrtc - not received any audio

Tags: android, webrtc, janus

I'm using the Janus mobile sdk client ( audiobridge plugin) for Android to create WebRTC connection, but after set local and remote description ( after the offer ) I've got the following error in the log:

```
2020-10-14 11:31:57.693 467-1923/? E/msm8916_platform: platform_check_backends_match: Invalid snd_device2 = 
2020-10-14 11:31:57.694 29505-29662/com.github.helloiampau.app E/AUDIO_BRIDGE: event
2020-10-14 11:31:57.703 467-1923/? E/msm8916_platform: platform_get_snd_device_backend_index: BE DAI Name Table is not present
2020-10-14 11:31:57.703 467-1923/? E/audio_hw_utils: send_app_type_cfg_for_device: Couldn't get the backend index for snd device handset ret=-14
2020-10-14 11:31:57.711 467-1923/? E/ACDB-LOADER: Error: ACDB_CMD_GET_AFE_COMMON_TABLE_SIZE Returned = -19
```

It looks like the Android couldn't find the speaker ?